# Can I remap my Notebook's TouchPad Buttons to a Keyboard Keystroke?

Tags: touchpad, remapping

Specifically, I want them to invoke my Browser's BACK-/FORWARD-Page functionality

Comment: You you want that, then you'd best provide the make and model of the laptop. Please only get the model # from the serial # sticker; any model name elsewhere won't tell us enough to find the hardware manual. Once you have that, click [edit] and add that to your question; please don't use Add Comment, but instead click [edit].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, you may be able to use a program such as [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to achieve this.

**Caveat**

If your touch pad sends "regular" keystrokes (ex. standard left and right mouse button signals), there is likely nothing to differentiate them from the same keystrokes produced by another device (e.g. your mouse). Thus, you will likely need an additional modifier key (not just e.g. the left/right mouse buttons).

**Example**

The AutoHotkey script below maps <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Left Mouse Button (`!LButton`) and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Right Mouse Button (`!RButton`) to the standard Windows media keys for `Browser Back` and `Browser Forward`.

*Browser_Mouse_Buttons.ahk*

```
!LButton::Send {Browser_Back}
!RButton::Send {Browser_Forward}
```

**Notes**

- `.ahk` (AutoHotkey script) files are simple text files with an alternate extension.
- [A full list of AutoHotkey keys is available here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I searched for sooo many hours for this before I found something that works.

There are several approaches:

1. Find a touchpad-driver that might have support for changing the touchpad buttons. You may search for drivers here: https://support.hp.com/no-no/drivers/laptops.
   But this might very well not work, you are lucky if your driver supports changing touchpad buttons.
2. Try to use intercept or AHI: http://www.oblita.com/interception
   https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=45307
3. Buy a mouse with a spesific software where you might remap your keys. For instance the ADX gaming mice, that comes with a software for changing the buttons.
   Remap your left mouse button, middle mouse button and right mouse button to F21, F22 and F23 (for instance).
   Then make an autohotkey script with the following lines:

#installKeybdHook
#UseHook On
Mbutton::ctrl
Rbutton::shift
Lbutton::enter
F21::Lbutton
F22::Mbutton
F23::Rbutton

I went for option number 3. Works perfect for me :D